# Load a bitmap to a PictureBox control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is not working for some reason. I'm not sure why:

```
        objBitmap = new Bitmap(Resource1.im);

        Stream stream;
        objBitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        this.pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        objBitmap.Dispose();
```

Basically, I need to show an image in a PictureBox control and I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pictureBox2.Image = objBitmap;
```

Comment: `Bitmap` subclasses `Image`, so this is easy-peezy (whatever that means).

Answer (score 4):

Well, it ought to go kaboom on the Save() method, the *stream* was never initialized.  Not sure what the point of doing this was.  There might be one but it isn't visible from your code.  The normal version is:

```
if (this.pictureBox2.Image != null) this.pictureBox2.Dispose();
this.pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.im;
```

With some question marks about what Resource1 might be.  You get my version going by using Project + Properties, Resource tab and click the arrow on the Add Resource button, Add Existing File.

Answer (score 2):

You can change that to

```
pictureBox2.Image = Resource1.im;
```

To answer your question, you need to put a stream (probably a `MemoryStream`) in the `stream` variable.
You'll also need to "rewind" the stream before reading it back into a Bitmap.  (`stream.Position = 0`)

Comment: Actually I can't do that because I have loaded the picture from the resource (Resource1.im) but I have changed colors of some pixels in the code so I want to put the objBitmap Bitmap object inside the PictureBox control. Resource1.im is the original image, I don't want to show that.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.