# Bitmap to Picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap

This question is related to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208015/using-httprequest-to-get-pictures-from-given-url). At the end, user does something like

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer,0,total));
```

Now, I want to display this image in PictureBox. So, what should be at the place of ??? below

```
pictureBox1.Image = ???
```

Comment: Try pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

Comment: `pictureBox1.Image = bmp`

Comment: Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120202/load-a-bitmap-to-a-picturebox-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pictureBox1.Image = bmp;`

That bmp is the image (`Bitmap` inhereits from `Image`) so you shouldn't need to do anything special.